# some question about the frame of the hector slam

Tags: hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone:

I am studying the hector slam .
I have some questions when I watch the some example about the .launch file:
1.what is the base_stabilized frame ?
2.what is the scan_matcher frame ?
Is there some special affect for them?

Thanks in advance:)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206091/some-question-about-the-frame-of-the-hector-slam/) by [Anthony Brooks](https://answers.ros.org/users/21690/anthony-brooks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

base_stabilized is the frame which provides height data of the robot relative to the map/odom/base_footprint frames, but does not provide any orientation data. Not too sure about, scan_matcher. It might be the output frame from the [laser_scan_matcher](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher) node. This node will match scans to a map, and publish a transform of the source based on feature mapping.

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anthony Brooks](https://answers.ros.org/users/21690/anthony-brooks/) on 2015-03-28**:
thanks,it help me a lot.